# how to fill multiline associative array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to fill associative array in bash from following example file

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
 mls qos trust dscp
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/6
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/7
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/8
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
```

`interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1` or  `GigabitEthernet1/0/1` should be the array key and anything between interface sections should be array key value.

```
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
```

Expected output should be:

```
 $echo ${array[GigabitEthernet1/0/4]}
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
```

There will be multiple different files with similar format, so this need to be done by loop, the text between interfaces should be 0 to 5-6 lines. The reason behind is I need to do logical test on each interface, if it is correct or not. Below text is correct, anything else, or empty field is incorrect.

```
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
```

So far i have stuck with formatting of IFS and multilines as the value of array key. I was able to fill non-associative array, but in not the cleanest form.

```
$ cat test_compare_interface | sed 's/interface.*$/*\n&/g' > test_compare_interface_sed
```

test_compare_interface is file with interfaces

```
$ IFS=$'*' && array=($(cat test_compare_interface_sed))
$ echo ${array[4]}

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust dscp
```

With associative array loop, i am still strugling

```
while IFS='*' read -r interface value; do array[$interface]=$value ; done < test_compare_interface_sed
```

Thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: You can store any string as a value in an associative array, and of course the string can also contain embedded newlines. In your question, I'm missing that you are showing the code you have written so far for this problem, and hence I can not see at which point you are stuck.

Comment: So far I was able to fill the non-associative array with the text. but also not in the cleanest form. i will edit the question to show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
declare -A array

# assign "${val[*]}" to the assciative array "array" keying with $1
store() {
    if [[ -n $1 ]]; then        # will skip the 1st line which is not ready
        array[$1]=$(IFS=$'\n'; echo "${val[*]}")
                                # join "val" with newline
        unset val               # empty the queue
    fi
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^interface ]]; then
        store "$interface"      # assign to the associative array
        interface="$line"       # for the next iteration
    else
        val+=("${line# }")      # append to the queue
    fi
done < file.txt

store "$interface"              # flush the last entry

for i in "${!array[@]}"; do     # print the array elements to test
    echo "$i"
    echo "${array[$i]}"
done
```

- It just read the input line by line without modifying `IFS`.
- If the line starts with "interface", it flushes the queue (array `val`)
  into the associative array and updates the interface name for next iteration.
- If the line does not start with "interface", the line is accumulated
  in the queue (array `val`)